# How to set the environment variable GUILE_WARN_DEPRECATED?

Tags: c, gcc, centos6, guile

I am using guile (version 2.0) in my C code (compiled in gcc version 4.8.5 and OS centos 6).

My makefile looks like this.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -march=native -O2 -pipe -ffast-math -I/usr/include/guile/2.0
LDFLAGS=-lm -lguile -lgc -lpthread -lfftw3f -llapack

.PHONY: all 

all: server mdclient_ash client

mdclient_ash: mdclient_ash.o

client: client.o mdlib.o ipp.o

mdmd: mdlib.o ${PROC_OBJS} mdmd.o ipp.o

mdmd.o: mdmd.c tsdmd.h

clean:  
    rm -rf *~ *.o sp/*.o sp/*~ pp/ff/*.o pp/fr/*~ pp/sf/*.o pp/st/*~  

pp/rte/*.o pp/rte/*.~  server mdclient_ash client
```

The compilation process warns for certain guile related errors, such as:

> scm_int2num is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/guile/2.0/libguile/deprecated.h:667) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>
> ```
>  element = scm_list_ref(retval,scm_int2num(1));
> ```

It has no errors. Upon executing my C file (main file i.e. `server.c`), I get the following error:

> Some deprecated features have been used. Set the environment variable GUILE_WARN_DEPRECATED to "detailed" and rerun the program to get more information. Set it to "no" to suppress this message.

How and where do I set the environment variable `GUILE_WARN_DEPRECATED` appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't execute C files like `server.c`; you compile them into a program like `server` and then run *that*!

Since the message appears when the program is run, you need to set the environment variable when you run the program.  I'm assuming you use a POSIX shell derivative such as `bash`; the syntax is different for C shell derivatives such as `tcsh`.

You can use:

1. `GUILE_WARN_DEPRECATED=detailed server` to set the environment variable for just this invocation of the program.
2. `export GUILE_WARN_DEPRECATED=detailed; server` sets and exports the environment variable and doesn't need to be reset again until you start a new shell in a new window, or something similar.
3. Add `export GUILE_WARN_DEPRECATED=detailed` to your profile (`~/.profile`, or `~/.bash_profile`, or perhaps `~/.bashrc` file).  This will now be set when you login or create a new window with a login shell.

There are some other ways to do these operations — they're minor variants on the options above.  Check your shell manual for which files are processed when it starts up.

Clearly, it is best to stop using the deprecated functions, so the detailed warning is the most appropriate setting to use.  However, you probably want to ignore the warning you're being given, not caring that your program will break in the future, and therefore you'll do the silly thing and use `GUILE_WARN_DEPRECATED=no` instead.  I can't overstate how silly that would be — do ***not*** use deprecated functions.  Edit the code and fix it to use the preferred replacement(s).

Comment: I am compiling them into an output file like server (didn't mention that in the question). And I am using the tcsh shell. I wanted to correct the depricated functions and am will be setting the variable to "detailed". Also, is there a way of setting the environment variable GUILE_WARN_DEPRECATED if I dont have root privileges.

Comment: Using `tcsh`, you need to use `setenv GUILE_DEPRECATED_WARN detailed` to set the variable to the best choice.  You shouldn't do development work as root — you don't need to be root to compile.  However, you set the environment the same regardless of whether you have root privileges or not (so `setenv`).  There are other ways to add that to the build environment (there's usually more than one way to do anything) if necessary, but simply using `setenv` at the terminal should be adequate.